# How to get a String^ into a 2d char array?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to copy characters from a System::String ^ to a rectangular char array.

First I tried: (along with some other code. not relevant to the question)

```
char name[25][21]; 

...

void savedata(int x, System::String ^ a){ //x is the student #, a is the name
    int b;
    using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices; // for class Marshal
    char* buffer((char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(a));
    x--; //So we write buffer[b] at data[0][b] when int x is 1
    for(b = 0; b < 21; b++){
        data[x][b] = buffer[b];
    };
}
```

and when I tried to run and debug it, "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'" occurred

Is there some easier/better way to put a String^ into a (2 dimensional) char array, and if not, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `.ToPointer()` to convert the result of `StringToHGlobalAnsi` to something that you can then cast to `char*`.

You should also call `FreeHGlobal` on the result of `StringToHGlobalAnsi` (or you can recreate an `IntPtr` from your `char*`).